# Precise Description of Intensive property in statistical physics

Tags: statistical-mechanics

As wikipedia says:

An Intensive property is a physical property of a system that does not depend on **the system size or the amount of material**(or particles) in the system.

I am interested in, why the definition below isn't right:

An Intensive property is a physical property of a system that does not depend on **the volume** of the system.

Comment: Volume is an extensive property. Is there more  to your question than that?

Comment: Function with degree of homogeneity zero.

Comment: @Emil, do you mean fractals?

Comment: @Aleksey Druggist: I have read the description of intensive variables as functions with degree of homogeneity 0. Something like $f(ax,ay)=a^0f(x,y)=f(x,y)$ for example. Homogenous function. Fractals is something like self similar functions? They can have a noninteger dimension. I don't know if they are homogenous functions.

Comment: @Emil, suppose we have a fractal set of material points with mass $m$ in space, then the density - the ratio of the total mass $M$ enclosed in the volume  $V$ to $V$ will depend on the volume: $\rho=\frac{M(V)}{V}\sim\frac{1}{V}$ under $M, V  \rightarrow\infty$, not $const$ !

Comment: @Aleksey Druggist: I am an amateur physicist/engineering physicist. But your function is probably a homogenous function of degree 0? I think the definition of intensive variables does not work as usually explained ("cutting system in half"). But density might be intensive if you add the exact same volume with the exact same mass next to it :-)

Comment: @Emil, the simplest fractal set, explaining  my first comment is the Cantor set (see, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set),  the only difference is that the elements of the set are not points, but segments with a constant linear mass